# Postdata confirmation box bypass?

Tags: c#, watin, confirmation, postdata

Ik working on some project, and there is one main problem I have. I'm writing some code that is performing some actions on the web, like posting data. But what happens all the time: Javascript code on the pages reload the page, just after i posted data, so it will ask for confirmation. I just need to know, is there any way at all to do this? I'm using C# with WatIn. I've thought of some ways myself:

- Disabling all message boxes, doesn't seem to work for this box.
- Detect when the box shows up and then press cancel, but I don't know if that's possible?
- Look in the Javascript code and when it tries to call the Reload method intercept that or something?
- Some other setting that disables this auto-reload? (tried some thing called METAreload i think but didn't work)

Google doesn't give me the information I need, I have been searching on this for quite a while now. Someone knows how to get rid of this box blocking my program?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally fixed it myself. There was a javascript function that would make the page reload when the timer was at 0. Just by putting javascript in the URL bar i could replace that function bij an empty one, and now it won't reload anymore!